# CalDav web application

Tags: calendar, caldav

**Is there an open-source web app for viewing .ics calendars?**

I have a server running the open source CalDAV server "DAViCal" to share calendars between co-workers.  I (the admin) add/delete the calendars and events, but I want to also host a web app that displays a human-readable calendar, so without any configuration my coworkers can visit a web page and see the calendar.  So I need a web app that does the following:

1. Creates a human-readable calendar (like month/week/day view) from an .ics file
2. Is open-source and able to be hosted on Ubuntu Linux so it's only viewable on my employer's network

Thanks

Comment: Questions on Webapps are out of scope of SuperUser

Comment: so serverfault? stackoverflow?

Answer (score 0):

Try either http://www.icalx.com/  or google's calendar (it can import ics calendars then you can share it with other people by emailing them an invitation).

Comment: sorry, but I need something open source that I can host (I made clarifications to my comment)

Comment: well, sorry aaron.  That's all I know of.  Good luck.